# Multiple CSS Selectors with Prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, css-selectors, sizzle

I'm refactoring some code that currently looks like this:

```
$$('#wrapper > div').each(function(e){ 
    if((e.id!='header') && (e.id!='footer') && (e.id!='content')){
        // various other stuff here
    }
});
```

I want to switch the initial selector and check for ID to a single line, something along these lines:

```
$$('#wrapper > div[id!=header]', '#wrapper > div[id!=content]', '#wrapper > div[id!=footer]')
```

The multiple selectors aren't working though, each selector on its own works fine though. Not sure if this is a syntax issue or what as the [Prototype docs](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/) say this should work but as soon as i add extra selectors then none work.

To confirm this works:

```
$$('#wrapper > div[id!=header]')
```

And this works:

```
$$('#wrapper > div[id!=footer]')
```

but this fails to select either (without throwing an error)

```
$$('#wrapper > div[id!=header]', '#wrapper > div[id!=footer]')
```

Comment: amended question so it should make more sense now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two code snippets do radically different things. The equivalent to the top snippet should be this:

```
$$('#wrapper > div[id!=header][id!=footer][id!=content]')
```

Your selectors would select all divs that have `id`, since those that are "`footer`" will be selected under "not `header`".

Comment: @Amadan, that was seconds, haha

Answer (score 2):

You can just append the selectors to each other `div[attr selector 1][attr selector 2]`
Please see the following [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epoch/FKacW/).

The problem with your initial attempt. i.e. using commas to separate the selectors, are that they are `OR`-ing. so even though you specify all three, each of the others will return what the others attempt to exclude.